# How to create a Russian doll-like stacking of z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to set a `z-index` value of CMS output in the following way: (the comments indicate the z-index number). This is quite an interesting problem, and is easier for me to illustrate than to explain.

It's helpful to imagine it like a Russian Doll where the `<img>`s in the first `<li>` are the outer layer, the next `<li>` is the second doll, and so on..

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 1 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 6 -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 2 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 5 -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 3 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 4 -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Similarly the, number of `<li>`s is not limited as more can be generated using the CMS.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 1 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 8 -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 2 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 7 -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 3 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 6 -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 4 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 5 -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking for a jQuery solution ideally as it's easier for colleagues to maintain but plain JS is fine.

Any help is appreciated, let me know if this is a duplicate as I'm not sure what the right keywords are to search for. Thanks.

Comment: This is quite unique... Have you confirmed that manually setting these z-indexes this way will get your desired result?

Comment: As well, what JS code have you tried so far?

Comment: No I haven't, hence why I asked. And yeah z-index works when applied using inspector

Comment: you can use jquery find to get the elements in dom order, from there it's just a simple loop with some math

Comment: I'd suggest looking into .each() and of course .child() and .parent().

No one's going to code it for you, but we'll help you when you get stuck.

Comment: Heck, you can even do that with CSS

Comment: This is rather simple, you could even have the next img scaled few % , but  the CMS generating the elements, now this makes it a bit complicated.

Comment: As a developer to a developer: Please, close your img tags (<img <!-- Stuff here --> **/>**)

Comment: Symmetrically up and down ... +1 / max -1 like stated below ...

Comment: @Bálint it's optional to close the <img> elements with a "/", as long is you're consistent.

Comment: Yeah, but most official style guides say that you should put the /-s there (like XHTML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a `.bg` is always followed by an `.fg`:

You need to get the elements with the class names `fg` and `bg`, loop trough them and set their z indices:

```js
var bgs = document.getElementsByClassName("bg");
var fgs = document.getElementsByClassName("fg");
var max = fgs.length * 2;
for (var i = 0; i < bgs.length; i++) {
  bgs[i].style.zIndex = i + 1;
  fgs[i].style.zIndex = max - i;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 1 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 8 -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 2 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 7 -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 3 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 6 -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="bg"> <!-- 4 -->
        <img class="fg"> <!-- 5 -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's beautiful! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to add the z-indexes in the CMS.

Looping through the items to be added and setting them might look something like the following (in simple php)

```
$total = count($items);
$max_z_index = $total * 2;

for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
    $foreground = $items[$i]->foreground;
    $background = $items[$i]->background;
    $foreground_z_index = $max_z_index - $i;
    $background_z_index = $i;
    echo "<img style='z-index:$foreground_z_index;' src='$foreground'>";
    echo "<img style='z-index:$background_z_index;' src='$background'>";
}
```

Comment: "I'm looking for a jQuery solution ideally as it's easier for colleagues to maintain but plain JS is fine."